# Regex to match anything not between HTML brackets, and after matching another string

Tags: html, regex

I have an HTML document which I need to match text in one block, and then match text in another block and put it into a capture group. I am using PCRE regex.

1. The first match will be a static match and stay the same. In the first block this is `>Match-Me-First<`
2. The second match to be put into a capture group will change. In the second block this is `>put-me-into-capture-group<`

I have the regex to match anything between ><, but I do not know how to have it match Match-Me-First, and then to the negative lookahead to do the capture group.

Regex to match anything between <>:
`(?![^<]*>)(\w+)`

First block of HTML:

```
<td width="270" valign="top" style="width:202.5pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 18.75pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><b><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Tahoma&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Match-Me-First</span></b><b><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Tahoma&quot;,sans-serif"><o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
```

Second block of HTML:

```
<td width="500" colspan="2" valign="top" style="width:375.0pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Tahoma&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">put-me-into-capture-group</span><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Tahoma&quot;,sans-serif"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex used:

```
(Match-Me-First)|(?<=>)([^<].*?)(?=<)
```